# Why are ceramic containers used for hot beverages?

Tags: thermodynamics

Why are ceramic containers used for hot beverages? For example, is it dangerous to use plastic? Are there any other reasons other than to protect hands from heat?

Comment: Some plastics may melt or release substances.

Comment: The plastics do release some terrible chemicals (you know that things (chemical release and plastic degradation) happen (exponentially) faster at higher temperatures). Secondly, light materials have lower melting/evaporating temperatures. Ceramics melts at thouthands of cendigrate and does not release the poisoness chemicals. These are basics. So, you know that and ask the question. How is it possible to answer?

Comment: I am not a graduate of physics so i figure out that could exist other reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polystyrene is used to hold coffee. Most plastics will soften or melt around 100 °C (the boiling point of water), although there are cups made out of plastic that will hold hot water.

As you know, paper (or wax lined paper) cups allow the heat to transfer too quickly (burnt fingers).

Ceramics transfer heat slowly and can be made to hold the liquid inside (instead of seeping through).

Comment: If anyone down votes, they should leave a comment on why?

Comment: @ChrisMueller I didn't think it was.

Answer (score 0):

Based on an experiment I just performed with my daughter (and a question I posted on this forum), I would say that metal as a material for hot beverages is a poor choice as the metal quickly becomes too hot to handle.  Ceramics heat up much more slowly and much less than metal, so that makes them a better material, although my experiment revealed that the ceramic also absorbs a lot of the heat from the liquid, thus cooling it more.